# Add class to all the components that are opened inside mat-dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm currently working with Angular 15 & Material library and I need to be able to add some styles to all the components that are in mat dialogs. By components I mean host elements of the components that was opened after `this.dialog.open(SomeComponent, {...})` - so the html is

```
<div class="mdc-dialog__container">
 <div class="mat-mdc-dialog-surface mdc-dialog__surface">
   <my-custom-component> <--- i need to add a class to this container
   </my-custom-component>
 </div>
</div>
```

This needs to be made globally, so all the components have the same class (or something else, i just need to be able to find it using css).

First of all, I used a selector `.mat-mdc-dialog-surface > :first-child` and it works fine - but I don't like this approach cause it depends on Material class and it could be changed in the future.
Then i was thinking about overriding MatDialog open method (so I can add additional functionality to it) but it didn't work. Now I'm thinking about using custom component factory resolver - cause MatDialogConfig accepts componentFactoryResolver. I was able to pass custom component factory resolver in one module - but I can't figure out how to add a class to the component & how to do it globally. Now it looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomComponentFactoryResolver implements ComponentFactoryResolver {
  constructor(private readonly _defaultResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  resolveComponentFactory<T>(component:any): ComponentFactory<T> {
    console.log('Custom component instantiation logic');
    
    return this._defaultResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
  }
}
```

I have a global config for all dialogs but I can't pass my custom component factory resolver. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
const DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS: MatDialogConfig = {
 ...,
  componentFactoryResolver: new CustomComponentFactoryResolver(),
};
```

but it requires 1 argument (ComponentFactoryResolver) and I don't really get how to get it here - cause new ComponentFactoryResolver() is not working, the error is 'Cannot create an instance of an abstract class'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it helps someone, I ended up with this class:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomComponentFactoryResolver implements ComponentFactoryResolver {
  constructor(private readonly _defaultResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  resolveComponentFactory<T>(componentType: Type<T>): ComponentFactory<T> {
    const componentFactory = this._defaultResolver.resolveComponentFactory<T>(componentType);

    const originalCreate = componentFactory.create.bind(componentFactory);

    componentFactory.create = (
      injector: Injector,
      projectableNodes: unknown[][],
      rootSelectorOrNode: string | unknown,
      environmentInjector: EnvironmentInjector | NgModuleRef<unknown>,
    ) => {
      const componentRef = originalCreate(
        injector,
        projectableNodes,
        rootSelectorOrNode,
        environmentInjector,
      );

      const hostElement = componentRef.location.nativeElement as HTMLElement;

      hostElement.classList.add(DIALOG_COMPONENT_CLASS);

      return componentRef;
    };

    return componentFactory;
  }
}
```

And then I used it like this:

```
export const customMatDialogConfigFactory = (
  customComponentFactoryResolver: CustomComponentFactoryResolver,
): MatDialogConfig => ({
  panelClass: 'dialog-container',
  autoFocus: 'first-tabbable',
  delayFocusTrap: true,
  closeOnNavigation: true,
  disableClose: false,
  hasBackdrop: true,
  restoreFocus: true,
  role: 'dialog',
  ariaModal: true,
  componentFactoryResolver: customComponentFactoryResolver,
});
```

```
export const materialModuleProviders: Provider[] = [
  ...,
  CustomComponentFactoryResolver,
  {
    provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
    useFactory: customMatDialogConfigFactory,
    deps: [CustomComponentFactoryResolver],
  },
];
```